# How can I add the same column to many tables with a query?

Tags: sql, sql-server

The following query is just adding a column to the table.

```
ALTER TABLE err.PreFinancePaymentPlan 
  ADD PackageName nvarchar(100);
```

I want to add this column to each table from the following query.

```
 SELECT TABLE_SCHEMA + '.' + TABLE_NAME
    FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES 
    WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = 'err'
```

Sample output from the above query.

```
 err.ColleteralValuablePaper
    err.CustomerPayment
    err.CustomerPaymentItemMatching
    err.DealerColleteralPercent
    err.DealerDistributorStatus
    err.DealerShellLimit
    err.DealerWaitingLimit
    err.DistributorPreFinanceLimit
    err.ColleteralValuablePaper
    .
    .
    .
```

How can I add this to the entire tablature in one single query?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SQL Server: drop table primary key, without knowing its name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1587812/sql-server-drop-table-primary-key-without-knowing-its-name)

Comment: iterate through the table name and write dynamic sql. here's a link https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1160/execute-dynamic-sql-commands-in-sql-server/

Comment: you can do through sql scripts  and generate dynamic queries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use dynamic SQL and a [cursor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/declare-cursor-transact-sql) for doing that:

```
declare @tableName nvarchar(128), @sql nvarchar(max)

declare tableCursor cursor fast_forward for
  SELECT TABLE_SCHEMA + '.' + TABLE_NAME as TableName
    FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES 
    WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = 'err'

open tableCursor  
fetch next from tableCursor INTO @tableName
while @@fetch_status=0 begin
  fetch next from tableCursor INTO @tableName
  set @sql='ALTER TABLE '+@tableName+' ADD PackageName nvarchar(100)'
  exec(@sql)
end
close tableCursor;
```

This will loop over all the rows returned by the query used in the cursor and execute the dynamic `ALTER TABLE` statement.

Answer (score 3):

Think out of the box:

```
SELECT 'ALTER TABLE ' + TABLE_SCHEMA + '.' + TABLE_NAME
  + ' ADD PackageName nvarchar(100);'
    FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES 
    WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = 'err';
```

Viola! Copy and paste the results of the above SQL and execute.

Ted.

Comment: update 'ADD PackageName nvarchar(100);' to ' ADD PackageName nvarchar(100);'.  A simple case of   missing  space

Comment: Thanks @Acewin. Corrected.

Comment: People do forget  to break the problem into getting something  really workable,    hence I like your solution. I    would have done the same rather than trying to understand and create  a   a lot   of        dynamic  script

Comment: @Yeou glad you like it! Every DBA should have done this many times!

Answer (score 1):

```
DECLARE @i INT =0;
DECLARE @count INT;
DECLARE @name varchar(50);
DECLARE @sql varchar(200);
SELECT @count = count(TABLE_SCHEMA + '.' + TABLE_NAME)
    FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES 
    WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = 'err'
DECLARE @temp TABLE(id int identity(1,1), name varchar(50))
INSERT INTO @temp SELECT (TABLE_SCHEMA + '.' + TABLE_NAME) as name
    FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES 
    WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = 'err'

WHILE (@i < @count)
BEGIN

    SELECT @name = name from @temp where id = @i

    SET @sql = 'ALTER TABLE ' + @name + ' ADD PackageName nvarchar(100); ' 
    --print @sql;
    EXEC (@sql)
    SET @name = NULL;
    SET @i = @i+1;
END;
```